# Passing a drupal field to civicrm report

Tags: drupal, civireport, custom-reports

We'd like to pass a Drupal field (Organic Group that a user belongs to) to a CiviCRM membership report. Has anyone done this and could give pointers or an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to do this with Drupal Views though I think you would end up needing to display a View within a View to deal with the multiple results you could have for both the OG memberships and the Civi Memberships. I did a quick proof of concept to check if all the joins were available which I attached to this [blog](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/view-display-contacts-civi-membership-and-og-membership).

Comment: Hey Pete, I just wanted to come back and let you know that this is pretty much what we implemented - thank you. One question: when we created our view, we used "User" as the data, rather than CiviCRM Contacts - and then just set up a relationship to open up the CiviCRM fields. Do you think this was the wrong approach?

Comment: Hi Alex. Hard to 'guess'. But yes I can see that you could start at either end of the daisy chain. I have often started at one end, and then if i hit any issues just reversed and built from the other end. Perhaps you could 'accept' this question and keep StackExchange happy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in code, you should be able to use the Drupal API to access all Drupal tables and fields in your code (`$result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node}")`;)